# Extended classes in a map (java)

Tags: java, class, dictionary, extends, inventory

I'm trying to make a basic inventory system in `java`. The items that are all keys to a `map` and all **extend** the `UsableItem` class. For example, `Tophat extends UsableItem`. The problem is I can't save the `myTophat` item/object into it without making the key type `Tophat`, thereby not being able to store other types of items. How do I make my `map` to store everything that extends `UsableItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare it this way:

```
Map<UsableItem, SomeObject> map;
```

Then you can add as keys whatever objects of type `UsableItem` or sub-types of it.

Comment: I know, I had to wait 10 minutes first, and then forgot, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powerful advantage of java generics "wildcards"

```
HashMap<? extends UsableItem, Integer>
```

Or

```
HashMap<T extends UsableItem, Integer>
```